# change php value with javascript

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

)

I work for pagination for my table, my problem is where I click "next" the javascript increase ( I show it with alert) and not php value, so I think the my page is not refresh

get php value :

```
<input type="hidden" name="page" value="<?=$this->page?>" id="page">
```

button next :

```
<li class="page-item" ><a class="page-link" id="page_sui" href="#" >Next</a></li>
```

javascript:

```
$("#page_sui").click(function{
    var val = $("#page").val();
    val++;
    $("#page").val(val);
    alert($("#page").val());
    });
```

Comment: What you need to do is read the page number from QueryString `$_GET['page']` and on click of the item do a `window.location='mypage.php?page=' + val`

Comment: You forgot the brackets after function: $("#page_sui").click(function () {...

Comment: @mokadem if Chris Michaelides' answer sufficiently solves your problem, please award the green tick, otherwise please edit your question to clarify the issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

PHP values cannot be changed through Javascript. When you click your button you are calling a Javascript function, and Javascript functions can only change  Javascript variables and DOM elements. If you want to navigate to the next page with your current code, change your Javascript to this:

```
$("#page_sui").click(function{
    var val = $("#page").val();
    val++;
    $("#page").val(val);
    window.location='mypage.php?page=' + val;
    });
```

And then in your PHP file add this:

```
if (!empty($_GET['page'])) $this->page = intval($_GET['page']);
```

Lastly, do NOT use `<?=`, it's bad practice!

Answer (score 0):

Your script is not communicating the request from the browser to the server. By writing `value="<?=$this->page?>"`, the server code (php) is putting the value in the HTML for the browser (javascript) to interpret and use. By writing `$("#page").val(val);`, only the value in the browser is changing but it does not send this request to the server to get more data. To do this you need to either navigate to a URL using `window.location` from javascript, or use AJAX from javascript to load the content you want and then place it on the page using javascript.